# Use of undeclared identifier 'CJSONDeserializer' ??? Xcode with json

Tags: objective-c, json, identifier

I have this problem in this method that uses json in xcode.(My xcode version is 5)
This is the statement with the error:

```
NSDictionary * dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
```

The error: Use of undeclared identifier '`CJSONDeserializer`'. but I already did declare this class in the project, so what I can do???

PLEASE HELP ME I REALLY NEED TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM ASAP.

This is all the method.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/json.php"]; // Modify this             to match your url.

    NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]; // Pulls the URL
    NSLog(jsonreturn); // Look at the console and you can see what the restults are

    NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;

    // In "real" code you should surround this with try and catch
    @try {
        NSDictionary * dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
        if (dict)
        {
            rows = [[dict objectForKey:@"user"] retain];
        }

        NSLog(@"Array: %@",rows);

        [jsonreturn release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error: ? Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithStream:options:error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's part of the [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) library. You should make sure you've included that library in your project. Also make sure you have imported the appropriate header at the top of your .m file:

```
#import "CJSONDeserializer.h"
```

Or change your code to use the built in `NSJSONSerialization`, e.g. replace the line that says:

```
NSDictionary * dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
```

With one that says:

```
NSDictionary * dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
```